# Unable to load selenium chrome driver from maven class path

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am running selenium for chrome and need to open google page. i am using testng and i have my chrome driver in the path \src\test\resources. i use jdk 1.8 and windows 64

i use the below code and i am not able to load successsfully

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("chromedriver-2.27.exe").getFile());
String path=file.getAbsolutePath();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

i get error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'NANSARI', ip: '172.18.240.141', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way and see if it works -

1. Put the ChromeDriver outside the project directory, say - C:\Selenium_Drivers
2. Code -

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium_Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get("www.google.com");
   ```

Please use the latest version of Selenium, ChromeDriver and Chrome

Comment: Hi Anish, if i put outside it works but i want to package it and run within my project folder.